# Compiling LibQGLViewer fails due to library not found lGLU

Tags: c++, macos, qglviewer

I was trying to compile libQGLViewer in OS X Yosemite but after executing `make` the following error appears

`ld: library not found for -lGLU
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[1]: *** [/Users/MyUser/Library/Frameworks/QGLViewer.framework/QGLViewer] Error 1
make: *** [sub-QGLViewer-make_first-ordered] Error 2`

I found that there is a library called `libGLU.1.dylib` under `/usr/X11/lib` but I have no idea on where to add that line in order to compile correctly the library. Moreover, I don't know if it is the right library that the compilation is asking for.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was easy to solve the problem by simply removing the following line

```
QMAKE_LIBS_OPENGL *= -lGLU
```

from all the `.pro` files in libQGLViewer